# Shell awk, how to escape question mark symbol

Tags: shell, applescript

I'm attempting to extract characters (using between approach) from a url string using shell. I'm stuck on identifying "?" character...

```
set sample to "https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523"
set extract to do shell script "awk -F 'subpath/|userId' '{print $2}'<<<" & quoted form of sample
```

...this will work but obviously returning "12345?". How do I also exclude the "?". "\?" didn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the `?` *character*, then use `\\\\?` in place of `userId` for the *value* of the `-F` *option*, e.g. use, `-F 'subpath/|\\\\?` instead of `-F 'subpath/|userId'`:

```
set sample to "https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523"
set extract to do shell script "awk -F 'subpath/|\\\\?' '{print $2}'<<<" & quoted form of sample
    --> "12345"
```

---

Normally to escape a *special character* from the *command line* in `awk` you have to use two *backslashes*, as shown in the *example* **Terminal** *output* below:

```
$ awk -F 'subpath/|\?' '{print $2}'<<<'https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523'
awk: illegal primary in regular expression subpath/|? at 
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
$ awk -F 'subpath/|\\?' '{print $2}'<<<'https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523'
12345
$
```

However, in an **ApplesScript** `do shell script` *command*, you have to double up on the *backslashes*.

Comment: awww.... tried "\?", "\\?", "\\\?" ... but not "\\\\?"  Thanks :)

Comment: @Pawel, Normally to escape a _special character_ from the _command line_ in `awk` you have to use two _backslashes_; however in an ApplesScript `do shell script` _command_, you have to double up on the _backslashes_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (hoping) that your snippet is part of a larger AppleScript, otherwise my immediate suggestion would be to write the entire thing as a shell script, which is essentially is already.

I believe in picking *the right tool for the right job*, and in this instance, both shell scripting and AppleScripting can do it equally well on their own, so calling out from one to the other is pretty lazy and irksome.  But, personal taste plays heavily in how we each like to write our scripts, so I'll leave it for you to decide whether you'd prefer to adopt either of my methods, or stick with what you've got since it's now working.

As your code is mostly `bash` script, I'll start there: **`awk`** is, of course, a very powerful scripting language in itself, and it can do lots of great things with text.  But it is *not* the right tool for the job here: it feels like grabbing a katana to slice some bread; it's undoubtedly capable of doing so but I don't think it was wielded in the most graceful manner, so you ended up with a mess.  I'm largely referring to the regular expressions that are tethered in being useful only when applied to the specific URL you've supplied, and using the word portions to target for matching, which is the last aspect of a string you want to be relying upon.  Here's how I would do it:

```sh
$ awk -F '^.*/|[?=&]' '{ print $2,$3,$4; }' <<< https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523
12345 userId 523
```

Using `'^.*/|[?=&]'` for pattern matching has a couple of advantages:

1. It should be immediately noticeable that this doesn't use any elements specific to your URL and, as such, will work with a huge range of URLs that typically adhere to a certain format (we can be fairly confident, for example, that the forward slash immediately preceding the slug `12345` will be the last one that appears in a URL that is correctly formed and properly-encoded URL, as any others that come after it need to be percent encoded).
2. You'll hopefully be pleased with the remarkable lack of back-slashing that goes on trying to double-escape things, which is one drawback of scripting in one language then calling out to another, and both require a string to be escaped specially for them, even though it has already been escaped once.  In fact, I managed to get the total number of back-slashes down to zero, as my regular expression doesn't contain anything that needs escaping.  Here's the same script embedded within an AppleScript to let you have a look and run it to make sure it works as is:

   ```
   set www to "https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523"
   set cmd to "awk -F '^.*/|[?=]' '{ print $2,$3,$4; }' <<<"
   do shell script cmd & www's quoted form
       --> "12345 userId 523"
   ```
3. The last benefit that will be of value to some and not to others is the improved efficiency and speed of the regular expression I went with when bench-marked against yours.  It doesn't always occur to people that regular expression matching is a complex, intensive, and reasonably costly set of operations to perform, and being a thoughtful in how you approach constructing them can---in more rigorous situations than this, of course---make a big difference in how performant a script is.  Using the pattern `subpath/|\?` requires 107 text comparisons to be performed to match the slug (`"subpath"`) and the question mark, which took 444ms.  OK, I'm quite sure you can spare 444ms for a script to run, of course, so I'm not suggesting it needs to be faster.  But, anyway, using `^.*/|[?=&]` reduced the number of operations down to 57, and took 216ms.  Thus a relatively innocuous change in our pattern means a script does half the work and so did it twice as fast.  To further illustrate the surprising effect on performance the results from a minor change to the regular expression, when I removed the caret (`^`) from the front of my pattern (which doesn't affect what it matches, and returns identical end results), the performance plummeted by 400%, requiring 209 text comparisons before making the matches in 901ms.  That's almost a full second, and so it's encroaching into a length of time you start to notice.

---

Having spent a lot of words discussing the `bash` method, I'm going to whizz through the AppleScript-only method, which will feel like I'm deprioritising it as less apt, but in fact, I would say that it's probably---in *this* situation---the better tool for this job.  `awk` is the katana, and ideally we would prefer a bread-knife, which we don't have, but AppleScript is the steak knife that is often a bit crappy, no way near as sharp, but actually ends up doing a really neat job without creating a mess.

```
set www to "https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523"
set my text item delimiters to {"/", "?"}
return the text items of www
--> {"https:", "", "someaddress.com", "path", "subpath", "12345", "userId=523"}
```

As before, it doesn't care what the specific URL is, as it will do the same thing to any well-formed URL.  Since the slug sits ahead of the last forward slash the occurs in a URL, and behind the only question mark that should appear in one, it will always find itself positioned second-to-last in the list of components into which this AppleScript decomposes a URL quite pleasingly.  Thus, the specific part of the URL that you want will be returned from this script:

```
set www to "https://someaddress.com/path/subpath/12345?userId=523"
set my text item delimiters to {"/", "?"}
set slug to text item -2 of www
--> "12345"
```